# Catch an error at nginx reload

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, bash, shell

I have a bash script that's make some operation on nginx's virtualhosts. I would like to know how to catch error if nginx not reloading correctly (`nginx reload`).

I think to use `nginx -t` but i don't know to intercept error in a bash script.

Comment: Do you want to log those errors somewhere then? In a separate file? Or simply echo the error message?

Comment: I want to determinate result of `nginx -t` (0-> not correct, 1-> correct) like a boolean

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to make changes and then direct reload Nginx ? It can cause Nginx to stop working.

A better process would be to make changes -> do a configtest -> if configtest == ok -> reload nginx.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

#...your script
nginx -t
if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
    echo "Error!"
    exit 1
else
    echo "All good"
fi
```